# How to detect Which user has logged in to chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

As chrome is supporting multiple user account in one browser, how can i detect which user is currently logged in to chrome in javaScript?? 
Example:
I have 'user1' 'user2' 'user3' accounts in my chrome, and when i run a function how can I get the logged-in user's name? Hopefully there is some method to find it out. 
Thank You

Comment: If this was possible, it would be a reason for me to switch to Firefox.

Comment: Is this for a plugin?

Comment: Not. Making this possible would lead to huge privacy problems. Why would you even want this information?